# gluLookAt seems to be producting wrong view, OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am working on an nbody simulator and I want to display it with OpenGL.  I want to always be looking at the centre of mass reference frame.  I have the following code.  I calculate the COM and I set the center coordinate in the gluLookAt function to be the center of mass. I then subtract the "zoom" from the z coordinate to get the eye position.  By logic this should ensure that I am always looking at whatever value the center of mass is.  The only issue is that I marked where the center of mass should be on the screen with a red dot and it is moving.  Shouldn't it never move if I am always looking at it from the same relative position?  Here is my code. Focus on the display function since I assume that is where the error will be.  I had similar code working in another project and I can't really find any differences.

```
#include "Universe.cuh"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "timer.hpp"
#include <GL/glut.h>

Universe u;
float* vbuf;
double angle = 0.0, zoom = 1000;
void display()
{   
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    float3 c = u.getCenterOfMass();
    gluLookAt(c.x, c.y, c.z - zoom, c.x, c.y, c.z, 0, 1, 0);
    glScalef(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    glRotated(angle, 1, 0, 0);

    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 0.25);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    {
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3d(c.x, c.y, c.z);
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (double)w / (double)h, 1.0, zoom * 1e9);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void copy_to_vbuf()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < u.size(); i++)
    {
        vbuf[3 * i + 0] = u.getObjects()[i].p.x;
        vbuf[3 * i + 1] = u.getObjects()[i].p.y;
        vbuf[3 * i + 2] = u.getObjects()[i].p.z;
    }
}

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y)
{
    if(c == 'w')
        angle += 1;
    else if(c == 's')
        angle -= 1;
    else if(c == '=')
        zoom /= 1.2;
    else if(c == '-')
        zoom *= 1.2;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void idle()
{
    u.timeStep();
    copy_to_vbuf();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    srand(time(0));

    u.getConfiguration().max_velocity = 10;
    u.getConfiguration().softening_factor = 0.01;
    u.getConfiguration().threshold_angle = 35;
    u.getConfiguration().time_step = 0.1;

    const int N = 5;
    vbuf = new float[3 * N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Object o;
        o.m = rand() % 100 + 1;
        o.p.x = 500.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX - 250.0;
        o.p.y = 500.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX - 250.0;
        o.p.z = 500.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX - 250.0;
        u.addObject(o);
    }

    copy_to_vbuf();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GL_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("N-Body");

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glPointSize(1.0);


    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `glRotated(angle, 1, 0, 0);` Are you not rotating the camera there from the orientation the `gluLookAt()` has set it to? On a side note, your `far` is too big, while your `near` is too small.

Comment: I kind of don't really want a far clipping plane.  I have never understood the point of the far clipping plane or why it is necessary.

Comment: It is crucial actually for the fact that GPUs have limited z-buffer. When you set `near` and `far`, you're defining the range your depth values will be distributed in. Think of it as if you have X labels you can distribute into a ruler of any length. The bigger the ruler, the less precise it becomes with those labels, but if its very small, your labels will be very close and one will be able to measure micrometers accurately using the ruler. The number of labels is analogous to size of your z-buffer. The only difference being z-buffer is non-linear (kinda logarithmic. look it up).

Comment: Ok. So what I seceded to do is just have a near filed of 1 and far field of 100 and I can just scale down the universe accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but remember, it's not linear. `near` plays a huge role in this. If it's big enough, then you can have much bigger `far` values. For example, `near` 20 and `far` 10000 will do very well, while `near` 0.00001 and `far` 100 would give very bad results. Check this article out for more detail http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/love_your_z_buffer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points regarding:

```
glScalef(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
glRotated(angle, 1, 0, 0);
```

1. Since your axis is not centered on the 'COM', when you apply rotation the COM point will not stay in place and logically would move around the screen.
2. AFIK the normal order is scale,rotate,translate for transformations. This will apply the rotation and then scale.

EDIT:

To expand on that: Currently you take an arbitrary point rotate it, scale it and then focus on the point where it used to be. If you want to rotate your model (e.g. point marking the 'COM') around itself, it needs to be centered at (0,0,0).